# Running a terminal command for every line in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, subprocess

I have a json file with tweets mined from Tweepy. To get a sentiment analysis for every tweet, I am attempting to use the API from www.text-processing.com. You can view my present (flawed) code below.

```
fname = 'python.json'
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        # Draw out the text from each tweet
        tweet_words = tweet['text']
        bash_com = 'curl -d "text={}".format(tweet_words) http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/'
        subprocess.Popen(bash_com)
        output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bash_com])
        with open('sentiment.json', 'w') as s:
            s.write(output)
```

It returns the following error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['bash', '-c', 'curl -d "text={}".format(tweet_words) http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I surmise this is mainly because I am using the format() function for a command that is suppose to go through the terminal (via the subprocess module). The terminal command I want to run for every tweet in my json file is:

```
curl -d "text=word" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
```

Does anyone know of a good solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash_com` is equal to `'curl -d "text={}".format(tweet_words) http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/'`

You're not calling `format` because it's inside of the string.

You shouldn't do that anyway, since it's insecure, you can use `subprocess.check_output` directly:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['curl', '-d', "text=" + tweet_words, 'http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/'])
```

But you should be using an HTTP library such as requests instead:

```
requests.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', {'text': tweet_words})
```